# Medir tempo que o usuário fica logado no sistema

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Preciso saber o tempo que o usuário passa no sistema.

Ou seja quanto tempo ele permanece, a partir do momento que faz o *login*, até fazer *logout* OU  fechar a aba/navegador/desligar PC/cair a conexão, etc.

Não sei nem como começar. Pensei através de `cookies` ou `session`. Porém não sei.

Minha intenção é guardar em um *BD* essa informação. Para que possa gerar um relatório de quanto tempo o usuário passa no sistema.

Comment: Você quer fazer o que com essa informação? Colocá-la no banco de dados ou não precisaria? No **caso mais simples** você poderia pegar o **timestamp** no momento em que o usuário faz a autenticação, o **timestamp** no momento do logout e verificar o tempo total logado. O evento de fechar aba/navegador você também consegue pegar, mas veja que isso não faz com que o usuário seja "deslogado", a não ser que você esteja forçando isso em seu código. Para perda de conexão você poderia fazer um **polling** através de função uma ajax...

Comment: ... e quando essa função não obter mais resultado você considera que houve logout. Mas veja que dessa forma o código ficaria do lado do cliente e dependendo como está seu sistema, não teria conexão com o banco de dados e tudo mais. Acho que o melhor mesmo seria tentar explicar qual a ideia final com isso, para alguém poder ajudar da melhor maneira.

Comment: @AdrianoLeal, minha dúvida é como eu vou armazenar no banco o momento do logout? Se ele clicar na opção logout, mil maravilhas, mas e se ele apenas fechar a aba, ou navegador...

Comment: @AdrianoLeal, acredito que a resposta do Papa Charlie, responda!

Comment: Sim, também achei a resposta do Papa Charlie muito boa, @DiegoZanardo. Não cobre tudo o que você quer, por exemplo, em perda de conexão os requests não funcionariam e você perderia esse controle, mas se levarmos em conta que perdas de conexão ocorrerão poucas vezes não haveria problema. Ah, também acho custoso toda sessão de usuário ficar comunicando com o banco a cada minuto, mas é uma alternativa, aí varia de caso para caso.

Comment: Outra coisa, atualizar a informação apenas no carregamento da página pode não ser o ideal, se suas páginas possuem conteúdos grandes (não sei o conteúdo do seu sistema) o usuário poderia ficar na página por bastante tempo, por exemplo lendo um texto ou assistindo um vídeo e você só registrou a data e hora de quando o usuário entrou na página. O cenário perfeito seria fazer esses requests no evento onClose de aba/navegador também, mas nunca fiz isso em JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela descrição que você deu, imagino que você não guarde sessão, muito menos cookie, e saindo do site deverá fazer o login novamente. Então apresento um exemplo simples de 2 tabelas.

---

```
USERS
ID | NOME         | SENHA | EMAIL...
1  | Papa Charlie | ***** | email@domain.com

USER-LOGIN
ID | ID_USER | LOGIN_TIME       | LAST_LOGIN
1  | 1       | 07/09/2014 11:00 | 07/09/2014 12:00 // login ontem
2  | 1       | 08/09/2014 13:00 | 08/09/2014 17:00 // login hoje
```

---

1) Quando o usuário fizer o login no site, grave em seu DB USER-LOGIN a última hora atualizada. A cada login entra um registro em `USER-LOGIN`, e a cada request é feita a atualização.

No exemplo das tabelas acima, o login de ontem durou 1 hora (11 as 12) e o login de hoje durou 4 horas (13 as 17)

2) O próximo passo seria enviar uma requisição via js para atualizar o campo.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.get("check_user.php");
} 60000 );
```

A cada minuto a página `check_user.php` vai receber os dados do usuário e atualizar o campo *LAST_LOGIN*

Comment: Eu estar mandando uma solicitação para o servidor e com isso alterando o BD, não pode causar lentidão e sobrecarga do BD e do servidor?

Comment: Você pode fazer uma atualização a cada carregamento da página, mas nesse caso teria um horário "aproximado" do logout.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez um código assim no Login:

```
//if(session["LogadoDesde"]==null)
    session["LogadoDesde"] = DateTime.Now();
```